# Vue component accessing data before it is available in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a component named `ProductArea` which displays products loaded from the `Prismic API`. The products loaded are dependant on a `category` which is selected by the user in a sidebar.

I'm using `Vuex` and struggling to come up with a flow that avoids a situation where `category` is not yet available in my store (`category` is also loaded from `Prismic`).

Here is what the parent of `ProductArea` looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <!-- <Header /> -->
    <main>
      <div v-if="!$fetchState.pending" class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex-1 min-w-0 bg-white xl:flex">
          <Sidebar :navigation="navigation" />

          <ProductArea />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar.vue'
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue'
import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'
import CategoryHeader from '@/components/CategoryHeader.vue'
import ProductGrid from '@/components/ProductGrid.vue'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Sidebar,
    NavBar,
    Header,
    CategoryHeader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      navigation: null
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const component = this
    await this.fetchCategories()
    .then(function(navigationResult) {
      const navigation = component.$store.getters.navigation
      component.navigation = navigation
    })
  },
  fetchOnServer: true,
  methods: {
      ...mapActions({ fetchCategories: 'fetchCategories', fetchProducts: 'fetchProducts' })
  }
}
</script>
```

I assumed having `v-if="!$fetchState.pending"` would prevent `ProductArea` from being created until `category` has been loaded into the store, however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is `ProductArea`:

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-white lg:min-w-0 lg:flex-1">
        <CategoryHeader :category="this.category" :products="this.products" />

        <div class="sm:p-6">
            <ProductGrid :category="this.category.primary.category" :products="this.products" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Locale from '@/types/locale'

export default {
    name: 'ProductArea',
    data() {
        return {
            category: this.$store.getters.category,
            products: Array
        }
    },
    async fetch() {
        const component = this

        await this.fetchProducts(this.category)
        .then(function(productsResult) {
            const products = component.$store.getters.products
            component.products = products
            console.log(products)
        })
    },
    fetchOnServer: true,
    methods: {
        ...mapActions({ fetchProducts: 'fetchProducts' })
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> Error in fetch(): TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

This error is referring to the undefined `category` within the `fetchProducts` called via `fetch` on the `ProductsArea` component.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What would be the optimal flow here to prevent `category` being accessed before it is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a default category.  If you don't want to do that, bring the Vuex `category` into the parent and only show `<ProductArea>` when it's defined:

Parent

```html
<ProductArea v-if="category" />
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['category'])
}
```

This is necessary because your `v-if` on `$fetchState.pending` only tests whether all the categories are loaded, but for the child component you also need to test that a `category` has been selected.

In fact, you can simplify all your code by mapping the getters instead of storing getters in variables, which is not a good practice.  Those variables wouldn't be updated reactively when the getter changes. Instead, completely remove the `data` options from both components:

Parent

```
async fetch() {
  await this.fetchCategories();
}
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['category', 'navigation'])
}
```

Child

```
async fetch() {
  await this.fetchProducts();
}
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['category', 'products'])
}
```

**Other improvements**:

- You can shorten the `mapActions` calls a bit:

  Parent:  `...mapActions(['fetchCategories'])`

  Child:  `...mapActions(['fetchProducts'])`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. There's a couple of other issues with my current code that mean I can't test this quite yet, but clarity around best practices/what works/what doesn't etc. is what I was looking for. 